# Как сравнить два словаря ? (Если ключи разбросаны)

Tags: python

Есть 2 словаря. У них есть ключ и значения. Ключ это название валюты : значение это стоимость этой валюты. Ключи в словарях разбросаны в разном порядке, как можно сравнить эти 2 словаря ?
Проблема в том, что валюты разбросаны и идут не по порядку.

Пример словаря:

> ```
> {"LINKUSDT": "7.7085", "UNIUSDT": "6.0023", "SUSHIUSDT": "0.6931",
> "COMPUSDT": "67.24", "AAVEUSDT": "71.519", "YFIUSDT": "6737.52",
> "DOGEUSDT": "0.074816", "CHZUSDT": "0.078843", "LINAUSDT": "0.013093",
> "ENJUSDT": "0.31141", "MANAUSDT": "0.403", "TRXUSDT": "0.08181",
> "XRPUSDT": "0.72112", "BTCUSDT": "29798", "ETHUSDT": "1873.49",
> "ETHBTC": "0.062866", "LTCUSDT": "92.29", "BCHUSDT": "246.6",
> "ETCUSDT": "18.5497", "EOSUSDT": "0.77449", "SHIBUSDT": "0.0000078946",
> "MATICUSDT": "0.743725", "1INCHUSDT": "0.316077", "MKRUSDT": "1034.31",
> "UMAUSDT": "1.615", "RENUSDT": "0.065403", "ZRXUSDT": "0.21033",
> "LRCUSDT": "0.22845", "BALUSDT": "4.499", "BNTUSDT": "0.381",
> "CRVUSDT": "0.7511", "YFIIUSDT": "776.1787", "WNXMUSDT": "29.9201",
> "BATUSDT": "0.2021", "CHRUSDT": "0.12021", "STORJUSDT": "0.3011",
> "SNXUSDT": "2.8104", "QTUMUSDT": "2.7006", "EOSBTC": "0.00002594",
> "XRPBTC": "0.00002418", "KNCUSDT": "0.607", "OMGUSDT": "0.6206",
> "BANDUSDT": "1.2638", "GRTUSDT": "0.11889", "OCEANUSDT": "0.36144",
> "NKNUSDT": "0.09519", "RLCUSDT": "1.1939", "OGNUSDT": "0.106",
> "CAKEUSDT": "1.5241", "BNBUSDT": "241.67", "ANKRUSDT": "0.0255095"}
> ```

Comment: А в чём проблема отсортировать словарь? `sortdict = sorted(dict1.items())`

Comment: А вообще - не обязательно, что бы они шли по порядку, просто пробегитесь по названиям ключей циклом `for`.

Comment: Словари сравниваются неважно в каком порядке ключи. Сложности могут быть только если в качестве значений вложенные объекты. А так просто берите и сравнивайте через ==

Answer (score 0):

Порядок ключей в словаре неважный — важно только то, какое значение определено какому ключу.

Предпологая, что ключи в обоих словарях те же самые, и что вы хотите сравнивать рост или падение каждой валюты:

```
result = {}

for key in dict1:
    val1 = dict1[key]                  # val1, val2 - строки
    val2 = dict2[key]
    num1 = float(val1)                 # num1, num2 - числа из этих строк
    num2 = float(val2)
    if num1 < num2:
        result[key] = "<"              # или какая нибудь другая строка, напр. "менее"
    elif num1 == num2:
        result[key] = "="
    else:
        result[key] = ">"
```

В переменной `result` будут те же самые ключи, но со значениями соответствующими результатом сравнения.

---

*Тест:*

Например, для словарей

> ```
> dict1 = {"LINKUSDT":   "7.7085", "UNIUSDT":  "6.0023", "SUSHIUSDT": "0.6931"}
> dict2 = {"SUSHIUSDT":  "0.7112", "LINKUSDT": "7.7085", "UNIUSDT":   "6.0000"}
> ```

будет в переменной `result` словарь

> ```
> {'LINKUSDT': '=', 'UNIUSDT': '>', 'SUSHIUSDT': '<'}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Если ключи попадаются разные то нужно проверить наличие ключа

```
fd={"LINKUSDT": "7.7085", "UNIUSDT": "6.0023", "SUSHIUSDT": "0.6931", "COMPUSDT": "67.24", "AAVEUSDT": "71.519", "YFIUSDT": "6737.52", "DOGEUSDT": "0.074816", "CHZUSDT": "0.078843", "LINAUSDT": "0.013093", "ENJUSDT": "0.31141", "MANAUSDT": "0.403", "TRXUSDT": "0.08181", "XRPUSDT": "0.72112", "BTCUSDT": "29798", "ETHUSDT": "1873.49", "ETHBTC": "0.062866", "LTCUSDT": "92.29", "BCHUSDT": "246.6", "ETCUSDT": "18.5497", "STORJUSDT": "0.3011", "SNXUSDT": "2.8104", "QTUMUSDT": "2.7006", "EOSBTC": "0.00002594", "XRPBTC": "0.00002418", "KNCUSDT": "0.607", "OMGUSDT": "0.6206", "BANDUSDT": "1.2638", "GRTUSDT": "0.11889", "OCEANUSDT": "0.36144", "NKNUSDT": "0.09519", "RLCUSDT": "1.1939", "OGNUSDT": "0.106", "CAKEUSDT": "1.5241", "BNBUSDT": "241.67", "ANKRUSDT": "0.0255095"}
sd={ "XRPUSDT": "0.76112", "BTCUSDT": "30798", "ETHUSDT": "1873", "ETHBTC": "0.062766", "LTCUSDT": "92.30", "BCHUSDT": "246.6", "ETCUSDT": "18.5497", "EOSUSDT": "0.77449", "SHIBUSDT": "0.0000078946", "MATICUSDT": "0.743725", "1INCHUSDT": "0.316077", "MKRUSDT": "1034.31", "UMAUSDT": "1.615", "RENUSDT": "0.065403", "ZRXUSDT": "0.21033", "LRCUSDT": "0.22845", "BALUSDT": "4.499", "BNTUSDT": "0.381", "CRVUSDT": "0.7511", "YFIIUSDT": "776.1787", "WNXMUSDT": "29.9201", "BATUSDT": "0.2021", "CHRUSDT": "0.12021", "STORJUSDT": "0.3011", "SNXUSDT": "2.8104", "QTUMUSDT": "2.7006", "EOSBTC": "0.00002594", "XRPBTC": "0.00002418", "KNCUSDT": "0.607", "OMGUSDT": "0.6206", "BANDUSDT": "1.2638", "GRTUSDT": "0.11889", "OCEANUSDT": "0.36144", "NKNUSDT": "0.09519", "RLCUSDT": "1.1939", "OGNUSDT": "0.106", "CAKEUSDT": "1.5241", "BNBUSDT": "241.67", "ANKRUSDT": "0.0255095"}
delta={}
allkeys=[]
allkeys.extend(fd.keys())
allkeys.extend(sd.keys())
for key_val in allkeys:
    if key_val in fd.keys() and key_val in sd.keys():
        delta[key_val]=float(fd[key_val])-float(sd[key_val])
print(delta)
```